# USB VBus Current Shaping

Tags: usb-device, usb-c, current-sink

I'm trying to solve a design issue regarding a USB device under development. The unit is quite similar to the [TS-80P](http://www.miniware.com.cn/product/ts80p-soldering-iron-main/) in that it implements Power Delivery and the main function is heating. We require both 9V and 5V operation using PD, USB-C current (1.5 or 3A) and the legacy USB BC DCP/CDP detection (1.5A). The heating stage is a simple FET-switched ohmic load. We perform a slow (30Hz) PWM and utilize reduced slew-rate switching to minimize HF emission.

1. What are the *di/dt* limits on VBUS sinking? I was unable to find this specified, apart from the current spikes during suspend in 2.0 spec *(picture)*. Or is USB EMC governed simply by EMI measurements during certification?

[image]

2. My colleagues tell me that it would be "OK" to exceed the current capability of the port short-term (say 2A peak PWM on a 1.5A source). Although this solution might work on most sources (given a high-enough frequency), this seems unacceptable to me; we don't incorporate a stepdown. We're not planning on certifying the device. Could such a solution even be considered for a USB-compliant device?
   [image]

Thank you for consideration.